# SUM function in NamedQuery of EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I am using following NamedQuery but getting error

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="getAvailableAmount", query="SELECT sum(tup.tran_amount) FROM TopUpResponse tup"),
    @NamedQuery(name="getUpFrontDiscount", query="SELECT (sum( abs( tup.tran_amount) )*.04) FROM TopUpResponse tup WHERE tup.service='BILLPAYMENT'")
})
```

Internal Exception: FailedPredicateException(arithmeticPrimary,{ aggregatesAllowed() }?)

I tried following format but still getting error

```
SELECT FUNC('ABS',tup.tran_amount) FROM TopUpResponse tup
```

Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [getAvailableAmount: SELECT FUNC('ABS',tup.tran_amount) FROM TopUpResponse tup], line 1, column 11: syntax error at [(].
Internal Exception: MismatchedTokenException(81!=32)

Regards,
Imran

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be bug in older versions of EclipseLink. I tried same queries in EclipseLink 2.0.0. Second named query and query utilizing FUNC are failing exactly the way you described, first named query worked.

In EclipseLink 2.3.2 all three queries work as expected. So somewhere between these versions problem was fixed. I do not know in which version exactly fix was introduced.

Only thing what you can do is to update to newer version of EclipseLink.